# Purge data using a while loop.

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a database that gets populated daily with incremental data and then at the end of each month a full download of the month's data is put into the system.  Our business wants each day put into the system and then at the end of the month the daily stuff is removed and the full month data is left.  I have written the query below and if you could help I'd appreciate it.

```
DECLARE @looper INT
DECLARE @totalindex int;

select  name, (substring(name,17,8)) as Attempt, substring(name,17,4) as [year], substring(name,21,2) as [month], create_date
into #work_to_do_for
from sys.databases d
where name like 'Snapshot%' and 
d.database_id >4 and
(substring(name,21,2) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))) AND (substring(name,17,4) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))) 

order by d.create_date  asc


SELECT @totalindex = COUNT(*) from #work_to_do_for

SET @looper = 1 -- reset and reuse counter
WHILE (@looper < @totalindex)
    BEGIN;

set @looper=@looper+1
    END;

    DROP TABLE #work_to_do_for;
```

I'd need to perform the purge on several tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roughly how many records are you purging each month?

Comment: It could be several million per snap shots.

Comment: Ok. And exactly what are you trying to accomplish with the query you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I delete large numbers of records, I always do it in batches and off-hours so as not to use up resources during production processes. To accomplish this, you incorporate a loop and some testing to find the optimal number to delete at a time.

```
begin transaction del -- I always use transactions as a safeguard
declare @count int = 1

while @count > 0
    begin
    delete top (100000) t
    from dbo.MyTable t -- JOIN if necessary
    -- WHERE if necessary

    set @count = @@ROWCOUNT
end
```

Run this manually (without the `WHILE` loop) 1 time with 100000 records in parenthesis and see what your execution time is. Write it down. Run it again with 200000 records. Check the time; write it down. Run it with 500000 records. What you're looking for is a trend in the execution time. As long as the time required to delete 100000 records is decreasing as you increase the batch size, keep increasing it. You might end at 500k, but this method will help you find the optimal number to delete per batch. Then, run it as a loop.

That being said, if you are literally deleting **MILLIONS** of records, it might make more sense to drop and recreate the table as long as you aren't going to interfere with other processes. If you needed to save *some* of the data, you could insert what you needed into a new table (eg MyTable_New), drop the original table (MyTable), and rename MyTable_New to MyTable.

Comment: I am needing to go into the tables that contain the daily files and then remove them with that snapshot name. My biggest table could very well remove 10 million records in the final daily download.  I can't truncate or drop the table because I have 7 years of previous records in the tables.

Comment: How many records do you KEEP in the table? Sounds like you need to do the second option. 1. Create a new table with the same structure. 2. Insert the records you want to keep. 3. Drop the old table and rename the new table to the old name. Again, if you're keeping 100 M records (for ex.), you won't want to insert those into a new table, you'll want to just batch delete what you want to get rid of. I would suggest you seriously consider an archive table for historical data.

Comment: Note that SQL Server locks the table if there is more than 5000 rows in transaction https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

The script you've posted iterating through with a while loop to delete the rows should be changed to a set-based operation if at all possible. Relational database engines excel at set-based operations like

`Delete dbo.table WHERE yourcolumn = 5`

as opposed to iterating through one at a time. Especially if it will be for "several million" rows as you indicated in the comments above.

Comment: For millions of records, though? That could destroy the transaction log. http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Answer (score 0):

@rwking where are you putting the COMMIT to the Transaction.. I mean are you keeping the all eligible Delete count in single Transaction and doing one final Commit?

I have the similar type of Requirement where I have to Delete in batches, and also track the number of count affected in the end.
My Sample Code is as Follows:

Declare @count int
Declare @deletecount int

set  @count=0

While(1=1)
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRAN
DELETE TOP 1000 FROM --CONDITION

SET @COUNT = @COUNT+@@ROWCOUNT

IF (@@ROWCOUNT)=0
Break;

COMMIT

END CATCH

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK;
END CATCH

END

set @deletecount=@COUNT

Above Code Works fine, but how to keep track of @deletecount if Rollback happens in one of the batch.